# setTimeout on .blur()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu bar that displays a sub menu bar on hover, and exits when a close option is clicked. I want to have a timeout option, so that the sub-menu closes itself after 5 seconds. I am trying to use .blur() for the main menu losing focus, and then setTimeout(function() {}, 5000); for the timeout portion but the event is not firing. Any advice? (The code contained inside the setTimeout(function() is the same as used to manually exit the menu)

```
$('#main-nav li a.main-link').blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#main-nav li a.main-link').removeClass('active');
        $('.sub-links').fadeOut();
        $('#sub-link-bar').animate({
            height: '0px'
        });
        $('#main-nav li a.close').fadeOut();
    }
    , 5000);

});
```

Comment: Do you mean to use mouseout instead of blur?

Comment: `blur` is only fired for form control elements.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp actually not: recent browsers apply it to every kind of element. Blur means, quite literally, *lose focus*. Focus can be given via tab, click, keyboard shortcut and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blur doesn't fire on mouseout, but when the element loses focus (formerly just form elements, now any kind of element). You might want to try `mouseleave` or, better, `mouseout`.